# How to get sitename from alfresco folder

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I would like to get sitename from an Alfresco folder using Java.
Actually, I could retrieve file name and folder but I could not get sitename property.

```
nodeService.getProperty(parent, PROP_QNAME_MY_NAME);
```

Could you please help me to get sitename from parent or nodeService?

Answer (score 4):

You should use SiteService:

```
* @param nodeRef   the node whose containing site's info is to be found.
* @return SiteInfo  site information for the containing site or <code>null</code> if node is not in a site.

SiteInfo siteInfo = siteService.getSite(NodeRef nodeRef);
String siteName = siteInfo.getShortName();
```